# How to show json data using jspdf in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I used jspdf to create a pdf file.I want to display json data in jspdf by using table. I used 'doc.autoTable' to display data in the form of table.How can i show the json data in a table.

**html code**

```
<button ion-button (click)="exportpdf()">Download</button>
```

**ts code**

```
exportpdf(){
    var item=this.display;
    console.log(item);
    var columns = ["Employee Name", "PRESENT","ABSENT","OFFDAY","LEAVE","LATE"];
    var rows = [];

    for(var key in item){
         var temp = [key, item[key]];
         rows.push(temp);
         console.log(temp,"temp");
       }


    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.setFontStyle('Bold');
    doc.setFontSize(14);

    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
```

[image]

Comment: share your json data

Answer (score 0):

Add the pipe in the template to see your items  `<pre>temp|json</pre>`

Them you will see your object output in the template.

Answer (score 0):

PRESENT field is a object

```
exportpdf() {
  const item = this.display;
  const columns = [
    {title: "Employee Name", dataKey: "EmployeeName"},
    {title: "PRESENT", dataKey: "PRESENT", displayProperty: "${yourPropertyName}"},
    {title: "ABSENT", dataKey: "ABSENT"},
    {title: "OFFDAY", dataKey: "OFFDAY"},
    {title: "LEAVE", dataKey: "LEAVE"},
    {title: "LATE", dataKey: "LATE"},
  ];
  const rows = [];
  for (let key in item) {
    rows.push({key: item[key]});
  }

  const doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.autoTable({
    body: [...rows],
    columns: [...columns],
    styles: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 14
    },
    didParseCell: (data) => {
      if (data.column.dataKey === 'PRESENT') {
        const prop = data.column.raw.displayProperty;
        if (data.cell.raw[prop]) data.cell.text = data.cell.raw[prop];
      }
    }
  });
  doc.save('Test.pdf');
}
```